# PhantomJS ReferenceError: Can't find variable: performance

Tags: phantomjs, karma-runner

I am trying to run jasmine test cases using Karma and PhantomJS as the browser.

I get the following error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: performance' since I have performance APIs provided by `Microsoft` dev tools added in my code.

How to get rid of this error? Also, how can I prevent PhantomJS from giving any JavaScript errors when running unit test cases?

Answer (score 2):

Performance timing API is now supported by PhantonJS 2 you can use the `karma-phantomjs2-launcher` Karma launcher https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-phantomjs2-launcher.

Comment: I get this in Phantom 2.1.1... 

`PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)
    ReferenceError: Can't find variable: performance (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_//5c670e1181742792c3be.worker.js:95)`